# moviepy.editor - сжатие .wav

Tags: python, аудио, видео, mac, wav

Взял аудио из видео:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("video.wav").subclip(0,6552)
clip.audio.write_audiofile("audio.wav")
```

Все бы хорошо, но .wav получился 1gb. Как его сжать?

Comment: Попробуйте конвертировать его в формат с кодеком, например в mp3

Comment: @gil9red Оформите ответом — приму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема заключается в формате выходного файла: `wav` весит больше,чем `mp3`.

Вот отредактированный вариант:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("video.wav").subclip(0,6552)
clip.audio.write_audiofile("audio.mp3")
```